# Why does my JS that's supposed to return an object return undefined?

Tags: javascript, class, object

Ok so as I understand my code, I created a promoSlides object, I a private function called init and in the return of a js closure (which I am not too familiar with) I returned init so I can use it outside globally kind of. When I run the file I get promoSlides is undefined, says error console of FF. I am not sure where I went wrong.  I am new to this so probably something is wrong. Oh and slides was defined in my original doc but I took it out for simplicity sake

```
var Slider = (function (name) {return name;}(Slider || {}));

Slider.promoSlides = ( function()
{
var slides;

var init = function(s)
{
    slides = s;
    sortSlides();
    startTimer();
    addListeners();
};
return 
{
    init : function a(s)
    {
        init(s);
    }
};

})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    Slider.promoSlides.init(slides);
});
```

Comment: "I defined a private function [...] so i can use it outside globally kind of": "use globally" and "private function" are usually pretty mutually exclusive concepts ;)

Comment: Check out http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding for a good rant on semi-colon insertion rules and line-break etiquette in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semicolon insertion strikes again!

```
return 
{
    init : function a(s)
    {
        init(s);
    }
};
```

needs to be

```
return {
    init : function a(s)
    {
        init(s);
    }
};
```

This is a result of a "feature" in JavaScript that looks at your line with just `return` on it, and says: "oh, you forgot your semicolon, I'll add it for you."

It changes `return` to `return;` so your function now returns undefined, and then you have some naked JSON sitting below it, which is the source of your error.  [Douglas Crockford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) actually describes this as one of the "awful parts" of JavaScript.

So the moral of the story is: *always* put your opening brace on the same line when you're coding in JavaScript.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - if I had a dollar for every time that happened to me :)

Comment: oh wow that fixed the issue, thanks. i did not know that one before

Comment: @user1058134 - you look like you already have a decent handle on JavaScript - you might want to take a look at that Crockford book I linked to in my answer.  It's about 100 pages long, and I've never learned more from a programming book than from that one.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the deadly "assumed semicolon" in the return line:

```
return //; <-- Javascript puts an implicit EOL here
{
    init : function a(s)
    {
        init(s);
    }
};
```

Change to

```
return {
    init : function a(s)
    {
        init(s);
    }
};
```

and your code should run.

Comment: yep it works thanks, the other beat you to it so i elected him as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The "assumed semicolon" issue was already described above. But don't use that much function calls!

```
var init = function() { ... };
return {
    init : init
};
```

works as well, or even shorter:

```
var slides; // unused variable ???
return {
    init: function init(s) {
        slides = s;
        sortSlides();
        startTimer();
        addListeners();
    }
}
```